Getting menu linkset items
I am using Drupal 10.2.6 and I am trying to get menu items via /jsonapi/system/menu/main/linkset, /jsonapi/system/menu/menu/main/linkset, and /jsonapi/menu/main/linkset, but I always get a 404 error.
The Menu Linkset module is enabled and the CORS are OK.



What is the point?

As per the documentation, the endpoint is at /system/menu/[menu system name]/linkset with no /jsonapi prefix (as the routes are provided by the System module, not the JSON API module).
So for a menu with the machine name main, the endpoint would be /system/menu/main/linkset.
This is also confirmed by core linkset test:
public function testBasicFunctions() {
  $this->enableEndpoint(TRUE);
  $expected_linkset = $this->getReferenceLinksetDataFromFile(__DIR__ . '/../../../fixtures/linkset/linkset-menu-main.json');
  $response = $this->doRequest('GET', Url::fromUri('base:/system/menu/main/linkset'));
  $this->assertSame('application/linkset+json', $response->getHeaderLine('content-type'));
  $this->assertSame($expected_linkset, Json::decode((string) $response->getBody()));

See how the test makes a GET request to base:/system/menu/main/linkset, not base:/jsonapi/system/menu/main/linkset.
